# how to count Number of hidden input Elements in Div

Tags: jquery, count

```
here is the code :

   <div class="upload"><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="SWFUpload_0_3" name="jpg_uploaded_files[]">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="SWFUpload_0_4" name="jpg_uploaded_files[]">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="SWFUpload_0_5" name="jpg_uploaded_files[]">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="SWFUpload_0_6" name="jpg_uploaded_files[]">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="SWFUpload_0_7" name="jpg_uploaded_files[]">
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" value="" id="SWFUpload_0_8" name="jpg_uploaded_files[]">
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the problem and what would you like help with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/PhVVM/1/)**

Try this

```
 $('.upload input:hidden').length
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong in case hidden field outside from div check: http://jsfiddle.net/PhVVM/2/

Comment: @AmitAgrawal for some reason you checked my first edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the attribute equals filter with the attribute `type`

```
var len = $('.upload input[type="hidden"]').length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='hidden']").length;
```

Comment: Sorry.. It was a typo.. Thanks for correcting me. I also realized it after posting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.upload').find($("input[type='hidden']")).length
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wf22s/)